# Getting the error Cannot resolve method 'join' in 'String' when using the join() method

Tags: java, android, string, date, leap-year

Essentially all I want to do is put each array element on a new line but when using the join() method I get the error, Cannot resolve method 'join' in 'String'.

```
public class revision_testing extends AppCompatActivity {

    start_timetable start_timetable = new start_timetable();
    revision_time revision_time = new revision_time();
    public int append_counter = 0;
    public int revision_days = 25; //FOR TEST
    String[] all_dates = new String[revision_days];

    String date=start_timetable.clicked_date;

    public int day=start_timetable.day;
    public int month=start_timetable.month;
    public int year=start_timetable.year;
    int [] days_in_months = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_revision_testing);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        for(int i=revision_days;i>0;i--){
            if (day >0){
                all_dates[append_counter] = year+"/"+month+"/"+day;
                day--;
                append_counter++;

            }else {
                day=days_in_months[month];
                month++;
                all_dates[append_counter] = year+"/"+month+"/"+day;
                day--;
                append_counter++;
            }
        }

        all_dates= all_dates.join("\n",all_dates);     //This line is the issue 
        }
```

Comment: all_dates is an array, and you can't call String methods (static or otherwise) on it. Use an `ArrayList<String>` instead.

Comment: @KKKKK: I don't think that String arrays (or Strings) have an `append` method either. You seem to also be missing the point that the OP is calling methods on a String array.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you wanted to use the [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method instead of `all_dates.join`:

```
String allDatesJoined = String.join("\n", all_dates);
```

You are also assigning the result back into the `all_dates` array. You need to tell Java which position in the array you want to use. If you want to assign to the first array position, use `all_dates[0]`:

```
all_dates[0] = allDatesJoined;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your logic using Java8 stream API as below.

**`System.out.println( Arrays.stream(all_dates).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));`**

You can use any delimiter. Here i had used **`','`**, but you can use **`\n`** as well.

**`Arrays.stream(all_dates).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));`**

You will get detail information about  [**`Collctors.joining`**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-8-streams-collectors-joining-method-with-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot assign the result of the joining operation to all_dates to itself, because it is a `String[]`.  You will need to assign the results to a `String` variable.

You can concatenate the contents of the array with newlines by using the Java 8 Stream API as shown below:

```
String all_dates_concatentated = Arrays.stream(all_dates).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

For more details you can refer to the Javadoc for the [java.util.stream.Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class

Answer (score 1):

I can see three problems with your code:

1. **Problem#1 - Not considering leap years**: You are always using `28` days for `Feb` which is not correct. A leap year has `29` days. This is where is [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) API comes handy e.g.

   ```
   import java.time.Month;
   import java.time.Year;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           int year1 = 2019;
           int year2 = 2020;
           int month = 1;

           int lengthOfMonth = Month.values()[month].length(Year.of(year1).isLeap());
           System.out.println("Length of Feb in the year, " + year1 + " is " + lengthOfMonth);

           lengthOfMonth = Month.values()[month].length(Year.of(year2).isLeap());
           System.out.println("Length of Feb in the year, " + year2 + " is " + lengthOfMonth);
       }
   }
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Length of Feb in the year, 2019 is 28
   Length of Feb in the year, 2020 is 29
   ```

   **Thus,** you should remove the array, `days_in_months` from your code and replace `day=days_in_months[month]` with `day = Month.values()[month].length(Year.of(year).isLeap())`
2. **Problem#2 - Trying to call `static` function, [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) in a non-static way and that too on an array variable instead of a `String` varaible**: you need to use it as `String.join("\n", all_dates)`.
3. **Problem#3 - Trying to assign the joined strings to an array**: Note that `String.join` returns a `String` value, not an array. Therefore, you need to assign the joined strings to a `String` variable (e.g. `String allDatesStr = String.join("\n", all_dates)`), not an array variable.